validate the number of affected rows by "update" and "delete" change types
In Liquibase, update and delete change types use a where query to target a number of rows.
Is there a way to enforce the number of affected rows by these two change types?
Something like the following:
update:
  tableName: MY_TABLE
  columns:
  - column: {name: col1, value: col1_value}
  where: col2 = 'col2_value'
  expectedResult: 2

The preConditions is not a suitable solution as:

the corresponding query is maintained and executed separately from change type's query
changes can contain many update/delete queries


You can use sqlCheck preCondition for this.
Just duplicate the condition of you update/delete changeSet in the sql expression of the sqlCheck preCondition and validate returned number of rows.
I'm not very familiar with yaml notation, but I it'll look something like this:
changeSet:
     id:  foo
     author: bar
     preConditions:
       - onFail: MARK_RAN
       - sqlCheck:
          expectedResult: 2
          sql: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE col2 = 'col2_value'
     changes:
     - update:
        tableName: MY_TABLE
        columns:
        - column: {name: col1, value: col1_value}
        where: col2 = 'col2_value'


If you can't use preConditions, then you can use plain SQL to implement the logic.
If you want to delete/update something by a certain condition and you know the number of rows that should be affected, then you can write the following query:
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @numberOfRows
FROM my_table
WHERE col2 = 'col2_value';

IF @numberOfRows = 2 THEN
    DELETE FROM my_table
    WHERE col2 = 'col2_value';
END IF;

COMMIT;

or the following query should work:
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE col2 = 'col2_value'
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE col2 = 'col2_value') = 2;

Liquibase does not offer any return from the changes, so you'll have to construct some custom logic for this.

As mentioned in my question, sqlCheck preCondition is not suitable for the mentioned reasons. All the RDBMSs I'm aware of, returns the affected rows after executing update or delete. The best solution would be enhancing update and delete change types to make use of it as it is done for sqlCheck precondition.

@Younes, Sorry, my bad. Read the question a bit wrong. Check out the updated anser.

The first sql solution has both queries near each other (better for maintenance) however, it is not DBMS agnostic (not that good for maintenance). The second sql solution isn't appropriate as it doesn't fail when nothing is updated/deleted which is required. In all cases, you have answered my question: Liquibase does not offer any return from the changes.
